# Understanding how to use 3rd-party event handlers in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm creating a simple Angular app that uses Ace editor (via ui-ace) for on-screen text editing. I want a handler to run when the cursor changes which will update a model object when the cursor is in a certain location. However, I also want to be able to click a button to move the cursor to a particular location (and also update the model object if necessary). Here's a jsfiddle that demonstrates the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/fpzknzej/3/

The model object updates when the cursor is placed at the end of the word `print` on the second line. The problem is that the `$scope.$apply()` on line 30 will throw an in-progress error when the `Move Cursor!` button is pressed. However, without that line, the view bound to the model object will not update when the cursor is moved with the arrow keys.

My current understanding is that this is simply the wrong way to do this kind of thing and that I need to do something along the lines of wrapping the `changeCursor` event to operate solely in the angular world. However, I'm at a loss as to how to approach this task (custom directive seems to be the thing that comes up the most when searching for this type of thing?) and if there's a good resource for understanding how to interact with third-party event handlers within angular. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Will try to make this as simple as possible.

All angular core event directives such as `ng-click` , `ng-change` etc will automatically call `$apply()` internally.

In your case with move cursor you start the digest with `ng-click` then have a bit of a circular issue where the external ace event triggered from within `ng-click` is also going to call `$apply()`.

You really only want to call `$apply()` when events  that change scope  outside of the angular core need to update the view.

A short term workaround for your situation is to use `$timeout()` instead.
This will be added to the end of the current digest stack queue and will call $apply() once other digests are completed.

As for directive , yes, this code does belong in directive but you won't really be changing it's current structure ... just moving it to a different part of the app. For the short term that isn't going to change what is currently happening

Comment: Okay, cool. And I think I did understand `ng-click` et al. calling $apply and the end. Ultimately, though, I'm curious: what is the "right" angular-y way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Not a lot different than what you are doing. Putting 3rd party dom related interactions in directive is proper. Not 100% sure what editor needs to do dom manipulation wise or if you need multiple instances